# How can I debug a dynamically defined method with Ruby? (method created within repl session)

Tags: ruby, debugging, read-eval-print-loop, pry, byebug

Is it possible to debug dynamically defined method in Ruby? If so, how can I achieve it?

So I opened a new Pry session and first tried it like this:

```rb
require "byebug"

def hello(x)
  byebug
  x += 1
  puts x
end

hello(5)
```

It shouted at me with "*** No sourcefile available for (pry)". I was still able to step through the code, but I couldn't see the source.

Then I tried doing it like this:

```rb
def hello(x)
  binding.pry
  x += 1
  puts x
end

hello(5)
```

And now it's the other way round: I am able to see the source code, but I can't step through the code (when I type "step" it shouts at me with "NameError: undefined local variable or method `step' for main:Object").
Looks like Pry actually does have the needed source, but the debugger doesn't work unfortunately :(

I managed to do it in Python repl using IPython (It didn't work in standard Python repl though):

```py
def hello(x):
    breakpoint()
    x += 1
    print(x)

hello(5)
```

I would love to be able to achieve the same in Ruby

Comment: That's not dynamically defined. A dynamically defined method would be with, for example, `define_method`.

Comment: And I cannot reproduce your `binding.pry` problem. That code works perfectly fine for me; I don't see any "undefined method `step`" error. What version of ruby and `pry` are you using?

Comment: @TomLord: Thanks for pointing out that this can't be called "dynamically defined method". I thought that any method that is defined not in source code, but after program has started is called "a dynamically defined method"

Comment: @TomLord also for some reason I am not able to reproduce the problem in my snippet with binding.pry either. I am not sure what I was doing wrong, but I have just tried running it now and it worked fine this time. However I still managed to find a place where binding.pry doesn't work for me as expected: https://pastebin.com/pAPDNyiM

Comment: It worked fine for me when the code is in source file, but when I run it in Pry it does stop but there is no output at all, and when I type "frame" it says "NameError: undefined method `__pry__' for class `#<Class:#<Object:0x00007ff9a48de2d0>>'"

Comment: P.S. My version of Ruby is 2.5.1 and my version of Pry is "0.12.2"